# Any way short code my custom function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `foo()` and want to call it in three times as below

```
function foo() {
  // function code goes here
}

foo();

$(window).resize(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){foo();}, 300);
});

$('#div').scroll(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){foo();}, 300);
});
```

I want to know if there is any short way to call it in all three situations.

Comment: Nope, not really as you're using different elements with different events, there's no shortcuts.

Comment: looks pretty short to me :)

Comment: You can use `setTimeout( foo, 300 );`

Comment: `(function foo() { // function code goes here })()`

Comment: @u_mulder - IIFE out of scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo(delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {

        // function code goes here

    }, delay||300);
};

$(window).on('resize', foo);
$('#div').on('scroll', foo);

foo(0);
```

Comment: +1 Same thing like the other answer - no need to go inside the setTimeout if delay is undefined.

Comment: @Shomz - it's easier to use zero timeout than defining the function code twice, or calling another function twice etc ?

Comment: I thought a simple conditional statement would do it. Although, we are talking about nanoseconds of difference :)

Comment: If the function code is inside the timeout, how do you use a condition to access that function code without either typing it all twice, or moving it to a seperate function you can call immediately or inside the timeout ?

Comment: Right, right, I envisioned it differently in my head without reading your code carefully, sorry, ignore what I said.

Comment: One unnecessary semicolon, I think there is no need to add semicolon after functions closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

If your using setTimeout with foo a lot, why not move it inside the function with an extra arg?

```
function foo(time) {
    time = time ? time : 0;    //default of 0
     setTimeout(function(){
          // function code goes here
    }, time);
}

foo();

$(window).resize(function() {
  foo(300);
});

$('#div').scroll(function() {
  foo(400);
});
```

Comment: +1 Though you might not even go inside the setTimeout if time is undefined.